# Force Close Error in Expandable list

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create three level of `expandable list` from database. It work little bit upto second level.But when i select third level at some point it gives error like follows.
As we found it because of array values(but the resultant array can have values). So kindly check and revert back solutions.

**ERROR**

```
05-03 12:06:17.990: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.example.home.MainActivity$SecondLevelAdapter.getChildView(MainActivity.java:270)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1256)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1224)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1499)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1755)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1661)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1212)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1532)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-03 12:06:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are trying to access a value from ArrayList using an index which is negative or greater than the lenght of the ArrayList. Show us ur code.

Comment: acutally it just looks like he's ArrayList is empty and he tries to access an index.